# `plt.imshow` only produces the last image of a suplot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to print four samples of DICOM images to my notebook.

I've created the following:

```
import os
import pydicom as dicom
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PATH = '../data/train/'
files = os.listdir(PATH)

np.random.seed(42)
random_four = np.random.randint(0, len(files), size=4)
subplots = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(8,8))

for image_number in range(4):
    sample = dicom.dcmread(PATH+files[random_four[image_number]])
    axs[subplots[image_number]] = plt.imshow(sample.pixel_array, cmap='gray')
```

This produces a subplot, but only the last image actually shows:
[image: Subplots]

How do I correctly print all four of these images to a notebook using subplots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Axes.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html).

Also you can use `zip` and `axs.ravel()` to loop over the subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8,8))

for ax, image_number in zip(axs.ravel(), range(4)):
    sample = dicom.dcmread(PATH+files[random_four[image_number]])
    ax.imshow(sample.pixel_array, cmap='gray')
```

Or using `enumerate`:

```
for image_number, ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()):
```